# Kendo RecurrenceEditor Collapse Javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Is it possible to collapse the RecurrenceEditor inside the CustomEditorTemplate, if I change a value somewhere?

I have problems with the Start value of the RecurrenceEditor's datetime, it will not update before the RecurrenceEditor has been collapsed.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it my own, with some javascript calls:

```
    var value = $("#RecurrenceRule").data("kendoRecurrenceEditor").value();
    $("#RecurrenceRule").data("kendoRecurrenceEditor").value("");
    $("#RecurrenceRule").data("kendoRecurrenceEditor").value(value);
```

This will set the selected value of the dropdownlist as "nothing", and quickly sets it back as the previous value. It is done so fast the RecurrenceEditor will not collapse, but the "Until" time will be updated.

There might be a better way to do it, but this works for me.